# Android MediaStore Schema

Tags: android, database-schema, mediastore

I wrote a ContentProvider query to fetch all MediaStore external images with all 20 columns from the MediaStore.Images.Media class. The Cursor return for some columns the type null. Does that mean that this columns doesn't exist? Is this a device and android version dependent problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cursor's `getType()` method can return one of the 5 predefined types:

- FIELD_TYPE_NULL
- FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER
- FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT
- FIELD_TYPE_STRING
- FIELD_TYPE_BLOB

`FIELD_TYPE_NULL` value returned by `getType(int)` if the specified **column is null**.

The best way to check if column exists is to run code on `cursor`:

```
int value = cursor.getColumnIndex(myColumn);
if(value == -1) {
   //column exists
} else {
   //column doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I build a more generic way to Log the content of a cursor and was confused about the contract definition of Media and the real database Schema.